# How to publish webjar assets with publish/publishLocal in Play 2.3?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3

[Since Play Framework 2.3 assets are packaged into one jar archive file.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets#How-are-public-assets-packaged?) I would like to publish this jar automatically with the project, i.e. upon `publish` or `publishLocal` I want the assets jar to be published as well.

How to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Since playframework 2.3 assets are packaged into one webjar archive file."*? Could you share a link to the document that describes the feature? I can't seem to reproduce it.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets, section: "How are public assets packaged?"

Comment: Can you confirm that the assets webjar is only created when you `dist` and not `publishLocal`? I managed to have the assets jar created in `dist` only.

Comment: Yes, commands `package` or play! `start` also create webjar file, but `publishLocal` or (I suppose also) `publish` don't create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `inspect tree dist` I managed to find the task `playPackageAssets` that generates the assets file:

```
[play-publish-webjar] $ inspect playPackageAssets
[info] Task: java.io.File
[info] Description:
[info]
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/play-publish-webjar/}root/*:playPackageAssets
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:641
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  *:playPackageAssets::packageConfiguration
[info]  *:playPackageAssets::streams
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:scriptClasspath
[info]  universal:mappings
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:playPackageAssets
[info]  {.}/*:playPackageAssets
[info]  */*:playPackageAssets
```

A naive solution might be to *attach* the assets webjar as is generated by `playPackageAssets` to `publishLocal` task's artifacts. Add the following to `build.sbt` (the types are to show what you work with):

```
import play.PlayImport.PlayKeys._

packagedArtifacts in publishLocal := {
  val artifacts: Map[sbt.Artifact, java.io.File] = (packagedArtifacts in publishLocal).value
  val assets: java.io.File = (playPackageAssets in Compile).value
  artifacts + (Artifact(moduleName.value, "asset", "jar", "assets") -> assets)
}
```

Repeat it for the other tasks you want to exhibit similar behaviour.

I'm however quite doubtful it's the best solution.

Comment: Using these changes in build.sbt file, cause to publish assets file in a jar file on `assets` folder in ivy. but for adding a jar dependency in another sbt projects, the jar files should be in `jars` folder.

Comment: NO! using classifier in sbt file cause to search for libraryName-assets in `jars` folder and not assets folder means: `C:\Users\M.Kashi\.ivy2\local\com.rh\??_2.11\1.0-SNAPSHOT\jars\??_2.11-assets.jar`

Comment: resolved. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322655/publish-asset-files-of-play-framework-plugin/26402840#26402840