# Publish asset files of play framework plugin

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

using `publishTo` in `build.sbt` file, it can be [automation the publishing progress](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist#Publishing-to-a-Maven-(or-Ivy)-repository).
But asset files( in `public` folder) does not packaged. how to package and publish asset files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to publish webjar assets with publish/publishLocal in Play 2.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089472/how-to-publish-webjar-assets-with-publish-publishlocal-in-play-2-3)

Comment: Linked question does not cover my problem. I need to use assets files like a webjar in another project but I cant import assets jar file to build .sbt file because they are placed in `assets` folder in published location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For locally publishing assets files , add this snippet in `build.sbt` file

```
import play.PlayImport.PlayKeys._

packagedArtifacts in publishLocal := {
  val artifacts: Map[sbt.Artifact, java.io.File] = (packagedArtifacts in publishLocal).value
  val assets: java.io.File = (playPackageAssets in Compile).value
  artifacts + (Artifact(moduleName.value, "jar", "jar", "assets") -> assets)
}
```

Important notes in last function line:

first `jar` specify package type folder (As webJars added as java dependency they should put in jars folder).

second `jar` specify extention of packaged file.

`assets` is classifier ([more information about sbt classifier](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html))

now you can use packaged assets as webjar in another project using this command in `buil.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies ++=   "organization" % "pluginName_scalaVersion" % "version" classifier "assets"
```

Comment: That works great. If trying to publish to an artifact/ivy server like artifactory, a replacing the "publishLocal" with just "publish" works too

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some directory (e. g. "public") into a jar, just add this lines in build.sbt

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
...
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ++= directory("public")
```

From [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#mappingshelper) and [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Howto/package.html#contents).

Answer (score 0):

The question title mentions "plugin" but I'm not sure from the rest of the question whether your intention is to deploy a Play web application to production, push a Play web application to a Maven repository (as in the link) or push a Play plugin to a Maven repo.

Assuming the first case, my own process to deploy a Play web app to production does this with bash scripts:

1. Run `play dist`

   (This includes the public assets)
2. Optional: repackage the archive

   (You can skip this but I found I can reduce the size by about 30%)
3. Copy the archive to the production host, e.g. with `scp`.
4. Unpack the archive to where it is going to run
5. Unpack *from within the archive* the public assets and ensure `nginx` or other front-facing HTTP server serves those assets directly.

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26312969/963195) may also be useful.

Comment: play command no longer available in play framework 2.3. and I need to publish automatically via a webjar